# How to Extend a Sealed Class Property

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose you have in a compiled file (dll) a class that is sealed and this class has a public property that is read-only like this one:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    public MyClass();

    public Guid id { get; }
}
```

and then you add a reference to your project.

My question is: Is there any way to add to the Property id a setter?

What I really need is to assign a value to this property.

Let me explain this a little bit more. We have an independent web app (A) that uses two dlls which to operate well makes web service requests to an external app (B). The App B has 2 different  dlls that almost contains the same classes. And the app A is using both dlls to make the requests. Now we are creating a new library for those classes that are “compatibles” each other (or at least have the same name) so that we have only one class to use. Now, I saw that in one dll this class MyClass has the property id read/write and, on the other hand, the other dll has the property just as read-only as I showed you earlier.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, it's horrid.  Classes are generally sealed for a reason, and read-only properties are read only for a reason.

Comment: I don't think it is possible and, even if it is, you shouldn't do it.

Comment: IF you really absolutely want to do this you will have to hack the .NET runtime... possible but neither easy nor recommended... if you describe the real goal/problem then perhaps there might a different way to solve it...

Comment: Perhaps you can expand on your question.  *What* is the DLL/class in question?  Why do you have to set something that is read-only and what do you hope to achieve?  Perhaps by expanding on what you are actually doing rather than focusing on this problem; we can offer a more robust answer than "You see what you're trying to do?  Don't do that."  :)

Comment: So given it's sealed and read only and the people who made it so, relied on that, exactly what do you expect to happen when you start poking totally unexpected data in there? Baaaaaaaaaaaaaad idea.

Comment: Well good idea or not depends on context. At home breaking rules through reflection means MOAR FUN! At work, I'd be having sleepless nights for the next few weeks as I wait for the really really hard to diagnose bugs to be reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First disassemble the dll with reflector or similar.
Then work out how the getter works. With a bit of luck it's reading a field and nothing else, but if it's doing anything more complicated then you'll have more to do in creating a setter. Lets say it is indeed a field and that field is called `_privateGuidField`.

The create a class that defines an extension method `SetId(this MyClass obj, Guid newID)` which gets the `FieldInfo`  for that field and calls `SetValue` on it.

This will only work with fully-trusted code.

Then sit back and wait for the class whose code-guaranteed invariant you've just smashed apart to misbehave in a really weird way. Don't complain to the people who created the class if it does, because you've just torn their code apart so there's no point complaining if it no longer works.

Comment: Based on your answer, the getter of the Property id, just was getting its value from a another property of the base class which is read/write and of course this allowed me to set the value I needed with no bugs or errors at all. Thanks =)

Comment: Sweet! You didn't even have to do anything utterly horrible (albeit kinda fun)

Comment: +1 for this answer. If the author made his class sealed your only fix is to Reflector/ILSpy and copy-paste all his code. Presumably he intentionally sealed it, and you're not going to talk him down.

Answer (score 2):

There is no legal way of doing it: the class is sealed, and the property is read-only. If the class implements an interface with the `id` property, you could wrap that class into yours, and provide a getter and a setter. As it stands, however, your only choice is hacking through reflection, and it's not a valid choice at all. Depending on how the property is implemented, it may be impossible even with reflection.